# Is there a way to sort points using a single pass?

Tags: sorting, math, geometry, coordinates, computational-geometry

I have some 2d points in space and I need to find the point `[xmin, ymax]`. I can do it in 2 passes using x and then y, but I want to do it in a single pass.

Is there a way I can combine these values into a single float so I can find the right point by a single sort?

I thought of doing `x+y`, but I don't know if that's reliable, most likely not, as from [5, 2], [2, 5], the last one will have higher priority.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't sort your point list to find maximum and minimum values, since that will take about O(n*log(n)) time. Instead, iterate through the list once, keeping a reference to the highest and lowest values you have found. This will take O(n) time.

```
min_x = myPoints[0].x;
max_y = myPoints[0].y;
for(Point p in myPoints){
    if (p.x < min_x){min_x = p.x;}
    if (p.y > max_y){max_y = p.y;}
}
```

---

Edit: from Wikipedia's Graham scan article:

> The first step in this algorithm is to find the point with the lowest y-coordinate. If the lowest y-coordinate exists in more than one point in the set, the point with the lowest x-coordinate out of the candidates should be chosen.

So, finding the min x and max y separately is inappropriate, because the point you're looking for might not have both. We can modify the code from above, to use these new criteria.

```
candidate = myPoints[0];
for (Point p in myPoints){
    if (p.y < candidate.y or (p.y == candidate.y and px < candidate.x)){
        candidate = p;
    }
}
```

It may be necessary to change some of these "less than" signs to "greater than" signs, depending on your definition of "lowest". In some coordinate systems, (0,0) is in the upper-left corner of the graph, and the lower you go on the screen, the larger Y becomes. In which case, you ought to use `if (p.y > candidate.y` instead

Comment: Actually I just tried but in the algorithm I think I am supposed to find the actual point with those values, otherwise purely value wise, the point might not exist. It's Graham scan algorithm.

Comment: @JoanVenge Do you mean you need to find the minimum point according to some variant of the lexicographic order?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to find the minimum point according to some variant of the lexicographic order (or even some other kind of order over 2D points), then simply traverse your set of points once but use a custom comparison to find / keep the minimum. Here is an example in C++, `min_element` comes from the STL and is just a simple loop (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min_element/):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Point {
    int x, y;
};

struct PointCompare {
    bool operator()(const Point& p1, const Point& p2) const {
        if (p1.x < p2.x)
            return true;

        if (p1.x == p2.x)
            return p1.y > p2.y; // Your order: xmin then ymax?
          //return p1.y < p2.y; // Standard lexicographic order

        return false;
    }
};

int main()
{
    //      + 3
    // + 4
    //      + 0
    // + 2
    //          + 1
    const Point points[] = {
        { 1, 1 }, // 0
        { 2,-1 }, // 1
        { 0, 0 }, // 2
        { 1, 3 }, // 3
        { 0, 2 }, // 4
    };

    const Point* first = points;
    const Point* last = points + sizeof(points) / sizeof(Point);
    const Point* it = min_element(first, last, PointCompare());

    cout << it->x << ", " << it->y << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to find a **max-min** point - a point with maximal y-coordinate among points with minimal x-coordinate, right?

If yes, you can store all your points in STL **multimap**, mapping x-coordinate to y-coordinate. This map will be automatically sorted, and there is a chance, that a point with minimal x-coordinate will be only one in this map. If it's not a single point, then you can scan all points with the same (minimal) x-coordinate to find a point with maximal y-coordinate. It will still need two passes, but the second pass statistically should be very short.

If you really want a single pass solution, then you can store your points into STL **map**, mapping x-coordinate into a **set** of y-coordinates. It requires more work, but in the end you will have your point - you will see its x-coordinate at the beginning of the map, and its y-coordinate will be at the end of the set, corresponding to this x-coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

1.can sort by  sort value: x+(MAX*y) or y+(MAX*x)

- where MAX is big enough value MAX>=abs(max(x)-min(x)) or MAX>=abs(max(y)-min(y))

2.if you have enough memory and need freaking speed

- then you can ignore sorting and use sort value as address
- x,y values must be shifted to non-negative
- x,y differences must be >= 1.0 (ideally =1.0) so they can be used as address
- there are no duplicate points allowed or needed after sorting
- create big enough array pnt[] of points and set them as unused (for example x=-1,y=-1)
- sort input points pnt0[] like this

  ```
  for (i=0i<points;i++)
   {
   x=pnt0[i].x;
   y=pnt0[i].y;
   pnt[x+(MAX*y)]=pnt[0];
   }
  ```
- if needed you can pack the  pnt[] array to remove unused points but this can be considered as another pass
- but you can remember min,max addresses and cycle only between them